# difference between “go up to” and “go up”

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, grammaticality

For example:

> She wants to go up to the mountain.

> She wants to go up the mountain.

As far as I know the first example is correct and the second is not. But by reading the rhyme

“Jack and Jill went up the hill...” I feel both are correct, so what’s the difference if both are correct?

Answer (score 1):

> She wants to go up to the mountain.

This means she wants to go *to* the mountain.

We sometimes go “up to” somebody, which means to approach them or to get “up close”. This does not imply actually climbing that person (or mountain).

> She wants to go up the mountain.

This means she wants to go *up* the mountain itself, such as by climbing it.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different meanings.  *Going up the mountain* would be used if you were **on** the mountain and in the process of **ascending** it.

*Going up to the mountain* would be used if you were not on the mountain, but approaching it.

Comment: Indeed, one could "go up to Mt. Washington" for a weekend and relax somewhere in the general vicinity of the mountain, or actually "go up Mt. Washington" and climb the peak.

Comment: @NuclearWang  You are correct.....thank you very much for the example.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence sounds like the addresser is describing that the girl is somewhere far away and she longed to go to the mountains.

However the second sentence describes the idea of the girl standing at the foot of the hill or the mountain and actually looking forward to getting on top, typically referred to as *hiking*.

Answer (score 0):

*To X* identifies a destination or target.

So *go up to X* means when you have completed going up, you are wanting your location to be X.

> She wants to go up the mountain.

No destination is specified.  So we don't know when she wants to stop going up.  It could be at the top or a point before.  Context/previous conversation/common knowledge might fill in that detail, or the precise destination might not matter.

Note that *up to X* also has a special meaning: it can mean to approach the border or edge of X, or in front of X, and this is especially likely if *up* is not being used to describe vertical movement.

> I'm going up to the front door = When I'm done moving I expect to be in front of the front door but not past it.

A related common combination of words is *up to the edge of X*.

... and this can be used to express a limit and have nothing to do with physical movement.

> He will give you up to 6 dollars = He's never going to give you 7 dollars.